# trying to use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, associative-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data which i want to use ng repeat on:

```
    $scope.doctors=[{patch:'BARIJPUR',doctor:'RAMA SENA',doctor:'SMRITI IRANI',doctor:'JAGDISH NAIR',
    patch:'KIRI',doctor:'ASHISH NAIK',doctor:'SMRITI IRANI',doctor:'SAIRAJ NAIK',
    patch:'JAMNAGAR',doctor:'RATAN PANDEY',doctor:'RAMAN SHIVOLKAR'
    }];
```

Im trying to use it like this:

```
    <div id='cssmenu' class="visible-xs" >
        <ul>
           <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Doctors</span></a></li>
           <li class='has-sub' ><a href='#'><span ng-repeat="doc in doctors">{{doc.patch}}</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'  ng-repeat="doc in doctors"><span>{{doc.doctor}}</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

the current output im getting is shown in the following link:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB9SB.jpg)

the expected output im getting is shown in the following link:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g9HC.jpg)

am i doing something wrong? have been at it for 1 and half hour now!

Comment: Why does your JSON has multiple identical keys? I don't think it's a valid object, can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: i am confused with creating the fiddle! see the images i have given! expected output andcurrent output! im confused if i have sefined the angular JS associative array correctly or not....

Comment: I have added my answer

Comment: It seems that patches are on the same level as doctors in your hierarchy. Shouldn't it be patch: { ..., doctors: { ... }}? This way you can easily do an ng-repeat on patches and ng-repeat on doctors within the patch.

Comment: No, they are two different (but related) keys on the same object - `patch` is the ... (IDK actually), and `doctors` is array of names of the same "patch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="doc in doctors">{{doc.patch}}
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in doc.doctor">{{cell}}
    </div>
</div>
```

try this

Comment: wow thanx a lot! that worked perfectly! saw the solutio n today! keep up the good work of helping evryone! oh nazeef re :-D i did not notice first!

Answer (score 2):

From your comment I assume that you're having a problem with the JS associative array, so here is an example of implementation:

```
$scope.doctors=[
   {patch:'BARIJPUR',doctors:['RAMA SENA' 'SMRITI IRANI', 'JAGDISH NAIR',]},
   {patch:'KIRI', doctors:['ASHISH NAIK', 'SMRITI IRANI', 'SAIRAJ NAIK']},
   {patch:'JAMNAGAR', doctors:['RATAN PANDEY', 'RAMAN SHIVOLKAR']}
];


<div id='cssmenu' class="visible-xs" >
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Doctors</span></a></li>
       <li class='has-sub' ng-repeat="doc in doctors"><a href='#'><span>{{doc.patch}}</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="doctor in doc.doctors"><a href='#'><span>{{doctor}}</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

#### Array definition

Instead of creating multiple `doctor` entities you should just create an array of them:

```
$scope.doctors=
[
  {"patch":"BARIJPUR", "doctors":["RAMA SENA", "SMRITI IRANI","JAGDISH NAIR"]}, 
  {"patch":"Anna", "doctors":["ASHISH NAIK", "SMRITI IRANI", "SAIRAJ NAIK"]}, 
  {"patch":"Peter","doctors":["RATAN PANDEY", "RAMAN SHIVOLKAR"]}
];
```

#### `ng-repeat`

You used it in wrong place. It should be applied to `<li>` element - which basically you want to repeat, not to `<a>` or `<span>`:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Doctors</span></a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="doc in doctors" class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>{{doc.patch}}</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="doc in doc.doctors"><a href='#'><span>{{doc}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dXSrWzyzUCCUhsMoV5I?p=preview)

Comment: no! still the expected result is not achieved! only patch is displayed: BARIJPUR,KIRI,JAMNAGAR....no sub menu is populated...dont know why! it should have been! i feel the logic you have given is correct but still no!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="row" ng-repeat="doc in doctors">{{doc.patch}}
  <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in doc.doctor">{{cell}}
 </div>
    </div>
```

yes this works for me! done! solved!